# Utility to strip parts of C header based on defines

Tags: linux, command-line, c

**NB!** This is not a preprocessor and `cpp -E` does not create a good result.

Looking for a small command line utility, which strips conditionally compiled parts of header files, based on parameters (CLI-parameters or environment variables preferred, but a config would do as well).

Example input:

```
#ifdef A
#define B 1
#else
#define B 2
#endif
```

Example output:

```
#define B 2
```

I found it once (something like `undef` or `undefine`), but can not remember it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're remembering [unifdef](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/). It understands definitions passed on the command line, including arithmetic. It doesn't parse macro definitions inside the file, only conditionals. It can parse some C preprocessor-expressions.

```
$ cat foo
#ifdef A
#define B 1
#else
#define B 2
#endif

#if A == 0x01
aye
#endif
#if B == 1
bee
#endif
$ unifdef -DA=0 foo
#define B 1

#if B == 1
bee
#endif
```

Comment: Yes! I also located this old SO question with a bunch of other proposals - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525283/is-there-a-c-pre-processor-which-eliminates-ifdef-blocks-based-on-values-define

Answer (score 0):

`unifdef` answers the initial remembrance question, but more contemporary options are:

- [sunifdef](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sunifdef/)
- [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/)